# How can I implement OneSignal push notification to java (not javascript) backend web application

Tags: java, spring-boot, push-notification, backend, onesignal

Is there a way I can implement One Signal push notification to backend web application that coded with java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take a look at the documentation Onesignal provides for installation usage on Java. It will work on Spring Boot with Java as well.

https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/java-client-sdk